# BindingContext in TabbedPage's Items is overrided

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a TabbedPage in my application, and I want to use a separated [View + ViewModel] for each Tab, and all the Tabs should be created in runtime.

This is what I have done so far :

**CategoryItem.cs**

```
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace BlankApp1.Models
{
    public class CategoryItem
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ObjectId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public long Position { get; set; }
        public long ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

**ProductsPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
            xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:BlankApp1.Views"
            x:Class="BlankApp1.Views.ProductsPage"
            ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryList}"
            CurrentPageChanged="TabbedPage_CurrentPageChanged"
            Title="{Binding Title}">
    <TabbedPage.Behaviors>
        <prism:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="CurrentPageChanged"
                                  Command="{Binding FilterProductsByCategoryName}"/>
    </TabbedPage.Behaviors>
    <TabbedPage.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Views:CategoryTab Title="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabbedPage.ItemTemplate>
</TabbedPage>
```

I know, The event **CurrentPageChanged** is used twice, but the one in **EventToCommand** doesn't work.

**ProductsPageViewModel.cs**

```
using BlankApp1.Models;
using BlankApp1.Services;
using Prism;
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using Prism.Navigation;
using Prism.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlankApp1.ViewModels
{
    public class ProductsPageViewModel : ViewModelBase, IPageDialogService
    {
        IPageDialogService PageDialogService { get; }
        private IDatabaseService _databaseService { get; }
        private IParseService _parseService { get; }

        public DelegateCommand FilterProductsByCategoryNameCommand { get; private set; }


        private ObservableCollection<CategoryItem> _categoryList;
        public ObservableCollection<CategoryItem> CategoryList
        {
            get => _categoryList;
            set => SetProperty(ref _categoryList, value);
        }

        private string _currentCategoryTab = "All";
        public string CurrentCategoryTab
        {
            get => _currentCategoryTab;
            set
            {
                if (SetProperty(ref _currentCategoryTab, value))
                {
                    FilterProductList();
                }
            }

        }

        public ProductsPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IPageDialogService pageDialogService, IDatabaseService databaseService, IParseService parseService)
            : base(navigationService)
        {
            PageDialogService = pageDialogService;
            _databaseService = databaseService;
            _parseService = parseService;

            FilterProductsByCategoryNameCommand = new DelegateCommand(FilterProductsByCategoryName);

            Title = "Products";
        }

        private void FilterProductsByCategoryName()
        {
            // Can't get this to work
        }

        public override void Initialize(INavigationParameters parameters)
        {
            if (CategoryList == null || CategoryList.Count == 0)
            {
                CategoryList = new ObservableCollection<CategoryItem>(GetCategoryListAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult());
            }


        }
    }
}
```

**CategoryTab.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="BlankApp1.Views.CategoryTab"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             Appearing="ContentPage_Appearing">
    <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <prism:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Appearing"
                                      Command="{Binding AppearingCommand}"/>
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAA"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**CategoryTab.xaml.cs**

```
using BlankApp1.ViewModels;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace BlankApp1.Views
{
    public partial class CategoryTab : ContentPage
    {
        public CategoryTab()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var vm = BindingContext as CategoryTabViewModel;
            vm.Title = Title;
        }

        private void ContentPage_Appearing(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            ContentPage contentPage = sender as ContentPage;
            var x = BindingContext as CategoryTabViewModel;
            x.Title = contentPage.Title;
        }
    }
}
```

**CategoryTabViewModel.cs**

```
using BlankApp1.Models;
using BlankApp1.Services;
using Prism;
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using Prism.Navigation;
using Prism.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace BlankApp1.ViewModels
{
    public class CategoryTabViewModel : ViewModelBase, IActiveAware
    {
        private IDatabaseService _databaseService { get; }
        public CategoryItem CategoryItem { get; set; }
        public DelegateCommand AppearingCommand { get; private set; }

        public event EventHandler IsActiveChanged;

        private bool _isActive;
        public bool IsActive {
            get { return _isActive; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _isActive, value, FilterProductsByCategoryName); }
        }

        public CategoryTabViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IDatabaseService databaseService)
            : base(navigationService)
        {
            _databaseService = databaseService;
            AppearingCommand = new DelegateCommand(Appearing);

            CategoryItem = _databaseService.GetCategoryByNameAsync(Title).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        }

        protected virtual void FilterProductsByCategoryName()
        {
            IsActiveChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            //PageDialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Test", "Some category is selected", "Cancel");
            var x = Title;
            var xx = 1;
        }

        private async void Appearing()
        {

        }


    }
}
```

The problem is that by using ItemsSource in TabbedPage :

```
ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryList}"
```

The BindingContext of the Tab View is overrided, and is no longer equal the instance of **CategoryTabViewModel** in the View Tab :

```
var x = BindingContext;
```

Returns a CategoryItem object inherited from **ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryList}"**

My problem is, the Commands in **Category.xaml** are not captured in the ViewModel associeted with it. The binding also not working.

My Question : How Can I pass a **CategoryItem** object to the Tab View, and be able to use Binding and send Commands to / with the ViewModel class (**CategoryTab.xaml** + **CategoryTabViewModel.xaml**)

P.S. : All the Views, ViewModels, Services, ... are registered in App.xaml.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution by my self.

So what I did is, insteed of using the tag `<TabbedPage.ItemTemplate>` to populate the Tab Pages, I did this :
Retrieve the ViewModel of the TabbedPage, and send the TabbedPage object to it (couldn't find another way to access xaml object from BindingContext ViewModel) :

```
public ProductsPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ProductsPageViewModel vm = BindingContext as ProductsPageViewModel;
    vm.MainTabbedPage = tabbedPage1;
}
```

In the ViewModel class, Add the Tab Pages using our List :

```
foreach (CategoryItem item in CategoryList)
{
    MainTabbedPage.Children.Add( new CategoryTab(item) { Title = item.Name  });
}
```

And now in the Tab Page constructor, get the CategoryItem and send it to its ViewModel :

```
public CategoryTab(CategoryItem currentCategoryItem)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var vm = BindingContext as CategoryTabViewModel;
    vm.CurrentCategoryItem = currentCategoryItem;
}
```

I know, may be it was the longest way, but it works just I wanted It, Creating Tabs according to my CategoryList, and using the CategoryItem to retrieve only the products inside this category.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem here:

```
    public CategoryTab()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var vm = BindingContext as CategoryTabViewModel;
        vm.Title = Title;
    }
```

Change it to:

```
    CategoryTabViewModel vm; 
    public CategoryTab()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm = new CategoryTabViewModel(...);
        vm.Title = Title;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, in MVVM, the BindingContext shouldn't be an instance of the ViewModel class at first ? Why should I create a new instance

Comment: A simple and a straight forward way to access your viewmodel is to instantiate it in  the constructor of your view. And then set the BindingContext  of your view to the new instance of that viewmodel. In case you don't want to instantiate the vm more than once, you can try the singleton pattern

Comment: I just saw that you are using prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True". I didn't pay attention to that before my answer. I've never use the prism plugin. May be someone with more knowledge in this regard can help you more.

Comment: Yes this is what I was trying to say, Prism should do all the registrations and inject all the dependencies automatically. Binding works just fine in the TabbedView page, but the problem is in Tab View child.

Comment: And I can't create an instance of **CategoryTabViewModel** as the parameters are injected by **Prism.Dryloc**